# Mac OS X (10.9) and 8192 bit certificates - Error -67762

Tags: macos, certificate

I've only recently upgraded to Mavericks and hence I'm not entirely sure whether this is a Mavericks only problem or not, but here it is:

Security update 2006-007 apparently broke 8192-bit certificates on OS X and no one bothered to fix it (https://discussions.apple.com/message/3650856#3650856). However there is (or rather used to be) a solution for this bug (or feature?) and it is in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2668985
You've just got to execute

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.crypto RSAMaxKeySize -int 8192
```

in a Terminal prompt. Well I did, then I also restarted my macbook. However this had no effect other than setting the RSAMaxKeySize. Here is how I know the defaults command worked:

```
ingenious@book ~  $ sudo defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.crypto  RSAMaxKeySize
8192
```

However trying to import a (valid!) 8192-bit self-signed certificate into my system keychain (using Keychain Access) I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: -67762
```

So, can anyone confirm this in 10.8.*? Is there any alternative way to make 8192-bit certificates work on OS X?

Edit: Could this thing actually be related to the new openssl in 10.9? (http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer, [as discovered by shizmob](http://shizmob.tumblr.com/post/67305143330/8192-bit-rsa-keys-in-os-x), is that Apple moved the location of this preference in Maverics to `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security`. So what you need to run is

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.security RSAMaxKeySize -int 8192
```

Comment: that certainly did the trick, thanks for answering :)

Comment: You're welcome. I’m always not quite sure whether I should “steal” other people’s solutions. I don’t even own a mac and only discovered this question because shizmob linked to it in his blog post (but didn't answer it). But if my post actually helped you solve your problem, I guess I did good ^^.